# How to tell if no data is returned from json jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im calling a url and getting json data back, If there is no data returned then I would like to be able to tell this with jquery. If there is no data to be return then the page that is called is blank.

Currently I have

```
var urlToGetJsonWith = '_Chapters.aspx?videoid=' + videoid;

jQuery.getJSON(urlToGetChaptersWith, function (data) {


}
```

But obviously if there is no data, then the call back function would not be executed.

Anybody know how to tell if no json was returned?

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: What makes you think that the callback won't be executed if the response is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assumption is wrong. The callback is fired anyway (except there was an error on the transmission itself).

So you could just check the `data` object within your success handler.

```
if( data && data.something ) { 
}
else {
   // empty object
}
```

One thing to mention:

> As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.